# Пакеты приложений в Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, linux-mint, manjaro

Вообщем планирую перейти на Manjaro Linux, сейчас на  Linux Mint. Вчера затестил в Live-режиме, всё понравилось. Так вот, вопрос следующий: Есть в Manjaro Linux аналоги пакетов приложений типа *.appimage или *.deb? Сейчас на Linux Mint у меня с 10-ок приложений в формате *.appimage и *.deb, храню как архив, чтобы потом, если я переустановлю систему я мог просто устанавливать их без подключения к интернету. Есть ли аналоги таких пакетов в Manjaro?

Answer (score 1):

Можно скачать пакет ввиде архива `tar.xz`, который потом можно будет установить.

Скачать (файл будет сохранен в `/var/cache/pacman/pkg/`):

```
pacman -Sw <package_name>
```

Установить:

```
pacman -U <tar.xz_file>
```